# Geometrical meaning of $\arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)=\frac{\pi }{3}$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> If $\displaystyle \arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)=\frac{\pi }{3}$, what is the locus of $z$?

#### My try

Let $z = x+iy\;, $ We get $\displaystyle \displaystyle\arg\left(\frac{x+iy-1}{x+iy+1}\right)=\frac{\pi }{3}$

$$\displaystyle \arg\left(\frac{(x^2+y^2-1)+2ixy}{(x+1)^2+y^2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

$$\displaystyle x^2+y^2-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}y-1=0$$

So the locus of $z$ is a circle.

#### My question

How can I interpret the following equation geometrically?$$\displaystyle \arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)=\frac{\pi }{3}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The given condition characterizes a set of "admissible" $z\in\Bbb C$. Since division of complex numbers amounts to subtracting their arguments, a point $z$ is *admissible* when you obtain the vector $z-1$ by turning the vector $z+1$ by ${\pi\over3}\>\hat=\> 60^\circ$ counterclockwise, up to scaling by a factor $\lambda>0$. The following figure shows what this means in terms of elementary geometry:

[image]

I'm sure you know a theorem from high school that tells you under which circumstances the angle $\angle(-1,z,1)$ has a given size when $\pm1$ are fixed and $z$ is variable.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
w=\frac{z-1}{z+1}\Longleftrightarrow z=\frac{1+w}{1-w}\tag{1}
$$
So the equation in question says that $\arg(w)=\frac\pi3$; that is, $w$ lies on a line through the origin at an angle of $\frac\pi3$.

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

[Möbius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) preserve generalized circles. That means that they send circles to circles if we include [lines as the limits of circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82220/a-circle-with-infinite-radius-is-a-line/82222#82222). Thus, we know that the image of the line $\arg(w)=\frac\pi3$ is a circle or line.

Since the $w$-line $\arg(w)=\frac\pi3$ passes through $0$ and $\infty$, the $z$-circle
$$
\arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)=\frac\pi3\tag{2}
$$
passes through $z(0)=1$ and $z(\infty)=-1$.

The real axis (dotted line) is preserved by both transformations. Möbius transformations are conformal; that is, they preserve angles. Thus, the angle between the black and dotted lines at $w=0$ is equal to the angle between the red circle and dotted line at $z=1$.

Knowing two points and the tangent at one of the points allows us to determine the circle geometrically.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a circle $\mathscr{C}$ centered at $O$ and $A$, $B$ are two points on $\mathscr{C}$. $A$ and $B$ split $\mathscr{C}$ into two arcs. If you pick an arbitrary point $C$ from one of its arc, the angle $\measuredangle{ACB}$ will be independent of your choice of $C$ and equal to $\frac12\measuredangle{AOB}$.

Let's identify the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ with the Eucliean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ 
and take $A = 1+0i$, $B = -1+0i$ and $C = z$. Remember,

$\arg(z - 1)$ is the angle between the line $AC$ and the real axis.
$\arg(z + 1)$ is the angle between $BC$ and the real axis.

This means $ \arg(\frac{z-1}{z+1}) = \arg(z-1) - \arg(z+1)$  is nothing but the angle $\measuredangle{ACB}$.

Since the corresponding angle $\measuredangle{AOB} = 2 \measuredangle{ACB} = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ is one third of $360^\circ$, the locus for $\arg(\frac{z-1}{z+1}) = \frac{\pi}{3}$ is an arc on the circumcircle for some isosceles triangle $\triangle ABD$ which has $A$, $B$ as two of its vertices.

Answer (score 0):

If the argument is constant, that means all the points lie on a straight line through the origin. Thus, $$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=r(1+\alpha i)$$
And:
$$|z-1| = r \sqrt{1+\alpha^2}|z+1|$$
Which means all points a distance $r_1$ from point $(1,0)$ are a proportional distance $r_2 = \beta r_1$ from the point $(-1,0)$. **This is just the definition of a circle**. From Wikipedia:

> Apollonius of Perga showed that a circle may also be defined as the
>   set of points in a plane having a constant ratio (other than 1) of
>   distances to two fixed foci, A and B